# Open images in browser from OpenShift's OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR generated path

Tags: java, openshift

I am developing an app that has been deployed to OpenShift. The app is made in Java using Struts2 on Tomcat server. The path for uploading images looks like that `String path = Constants.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + Constants.FOLDER_IMGS;`

where `Constants.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")`
and `Constants.FOLDER_IMGS = "/userfiles/images/"`

Now, it generates something like this in frontend `http://wed-brorb1.rhcloud.com/var/lib/openshift/556015d8e0b8cd2184000015/app-root/data/userfiles/images/1434877615630.jpg`, but image isn't showing, is this the wrong path? already pulling my hair out of my head trying to solve this out.

Comment: What HTTP error do you get when you copy the above URL in the browser address bar?

Comment: I have seen your site even http://wed-brorb1.rhcloud.com/var returns 404, it means that your folders _var/.._ is not under the web folder are you sure your folder structure is correctly set

Comment: /var/ is a folder under file system, it has nothing with web folder, this is how openshift works, and I have to find a solution to display images in browser.

Answer (score 0):

That path is a place where you can store files that won't be erased when you redeploy your application. That path is not a location that is automatically served via HTTP in any way. You can't just build a URL using that path. You would need to configure your web server to map something like `http://wed-brorb1.rhcloud.com/images` to the local `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/userfiles/images/` directory.

Also note that this directory is not shared across all your OpenShift servers in a scaled application. It's really better to store user uploaded files in a shared location like S3 or Dropbox.

Comment: I am trying that, but cannot make it work properly, I have also to give some permissions to that folder?

Comment: @Denees You shouldn't need to change permissions on that folder. You will need to say what web server you are using (Tomcat, JBoss, etc.) in order to get any more help.

Comment: Sorry mate, I am using Tomcat. I've updated first post.